# Group dataframes with MultiIndexes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

With a classic dataframe (fig 1), I would like to regroup the data so that I can generate easily the table in (fig 2).

Therefore, for this particular case, there should be 5 "Dataframes" with sub-dataframes: Precision, Recall, F1-score, ROC and PR. Fig 2 is only part of the Precision dataframe.

In short, I would like to create five dataframes, with sub-dataframes for each Train --> Test combination from the initial dataframe. Then, once that is done, each sub-dataframe should have the same columns (ML models in fig 1). Then, rows should be generated so that each Selection method is present for each sub-dataframe, for each ML model.

The data to fill in the cells is calculated as Average +- Delta.

I am currently looking into using multiIndex in Pandas, similarly to this:

```
def summarize_full_obs(df):
    
    multicol_1 = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples([('K562 → K562', 'XGBOOST'),
                                          ('K562 → K562', 'ADABOOST'),
                                          ('K562 → K562', 'RANDOM FOREST')])
    multicol_2 = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples([('K562 → GM12878', 'XGBOOST'),
                                          ('K562 → GM12878', 'ADABOOST'),
                                          ('K562 → GM12878', 'RANDOM FOREST')])
    multicol_3 = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples([('GM12878 → GM12878', 'XGBOOST'),
                                          ('GM12878 → GM12878', 'ADABOOST'),
                                          ('GM12878 → GM12878', 'RANDOM FOREST')])
    multicol_4 = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples([('GM12878 → K562', 'XGBOOST'),
                                          ('GM12878 → K562', 'ADABOOST'),
                                          ('GM12878 → K562', 'RANDOM FOREST')])
```

The code is definitely still a work in progress, but while I am looking on how I can achieve this, I prefer to also ask here, perhaps I am trying to reinvent the wheel for no particular reason and there's some magic function that does this more easily.

[image]

[image]

Comment: This is a little confusing because your Fig 2 is not really a dataframe.  It is more like a HTML table.

Comment: Yes, I am probably abusing the language a bit. At the end of the day, I would like to have the things in Fig 2 saved as CSV files, so 5 CSV files (Prec, Rec, F1, ROC, PR) with the structure here. Again, even as HTML, I wouldn't mind too much as long as I can reproduce this for later.